# Generating output on query string

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website in which I have to perform a certain operation. I have  to displaying the ID's from the DB on menu.aspx page in this format {1:2:3:4}. The above format is not a problem and can be just be written with

```
Response.Write("{");
for.. loop(until last ID)
{
Response.Write(query to fetch ID's) + ":";
}
Response.Write("}");
```

But here comes my question. I have to generate this ID when the user types the query within the URL somewhat like `http://localhost/website/menu.aspx?search=yes`

Note that I am saying **that user will type this URL**. I know that query string can pass the values from one form to another but this is a single web form and if I attach this `?search=yes`, it should return the result. How can this be done?

This is somewhat similar to searching in Google. For eg: I can type `www.google.com/search?Stack` and I get the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example will work if there is a querystring parameter named "search" with any value (including blank).

```
if (Request.QueryString["search"] != null) {

    Response.Write("{");
    for.. loop(until last ID) {
        Response.Write(query to fetch ID's) + ":";
    }
    Response.Write("}");
}
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty` already checks for null, so there is no need for `?? string.Empty`.  It should also just work directly as `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["search"])) {`

Comment: Where in the page menu.aspx.cs would I have to put this code?

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot. In continuation to this, can this made such that the user may type anything after search =(equal to) but it has to generate the same output. For eg: http://localhost/website/?search=code, http://localhost/website/?search=example, http://localhost/website/?search=whatever All of them should generate the same output.

Comment: Yes, I edited the code above so that if there is a url param named 'search' in the URL, it will output that code.

Comment: umm.. I have to change some things so that on this query string `localhost/website/?search=jessegavin` , the jessegvain should be appended to my output i.e jessegavin{1:2:3:4). Similarly for all other values searched through query string should be appended to the output. Can you please help me in this too?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Request.QueryString collection:

```
foreach(var item in Request.QueryString)
{
       Response.Write(Request.QueryString[item] + ":");
}

//etc.
```

Comment: Can this made such that the user may type anything after search =(equal to) but it has to generate the same output.
For eg: `http://localhost/website/?search=code`, 
`http://localhost/website/?search=example`, 
`http://localhost/website/?search=whatever`

All of them should generate the same output.